# In Unity, how to find the type of a missing script?

Tags: unity-game-engine, reflection

a few of my objects now have 'missing' scripts on them, and I can't remember which script they once were.

I can't just delete them because I don't want to lose their the fields. I don't know why, but according to my experience, the invalid scripts may still remember its public field values. If I find the correct script type, the fields will come back.

I find an article about this but still don't understand:

[How do I programmatically find name of missing script?](https://answers.unity.com/questions/749120/how-do-i-programmatically-find-name-of-missing-scr.html)

He uses `Component.GetType()`, but the missing scripts are `null`. I can't use `GetType()` of a `null`, is it? But someone says that article solves the problem. I am sure I missed something.

I really hope to find their types, or at least some hints, like public fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The import settings of a GameObject in a scene should be stored in the scene file. Simply search for the name of the GameObject in the meta file and you should see all the import settings including serialized values and components.

For example, here is a truncated version of the `MainCamera` GameObject (along with extra components on the object) extracted from the `.unity` (scene) file:

```
--- !u!1 &1834266099
GameObject:
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 0
  m_PrefabParentObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabInternal: {fileID: 0}
  serializedVersion: 5
  m_Component:
  - component: {fileID: 1834266104}
  - component: {fileID: 1834266103}
  - component: {fileID: 1834266102}
  - component: {fileID: 1834266101}
  - component: {fileID: 1834266100}
  - component: {fileID: 1834266105}
  - component: {fileID: 1834266106}
  m_Layer: 0
  m_Name: Main Camera
  m_TagString: MainCamera
  m_Icon: {fileID: 0}
  m_NavMeshLayer: 0
  m_StaticEditorFlags: 0
  m_IsActive: 1
--- !u!81 &1834266100
...
--- !u!114 &1834266105
MonoBehaviour:
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 0
  m_PrefabParentObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabInternal: {fileID: 0}
  m_GameObject: {fileID: 1834266099}
  m_Enabled: 1
  m_EditorHideFlags: 0
  m_Script: {fileID: 11500000, guid: ff26db721962cdf4a8edcdfa9a767d2a, type: 3}
  m_Name: 
  m_EditorClassIdentifier: 
  profile: {fileID: 11400000, guid: b7a430b0531a4cc44b388f7e3bf10d06, type: 2}
--- !u!114 &1834266106
```

As you can see, the name of the object along with its properties are stored here. The GUID of the MonoBehaviour script is given which can easily be cross-referenced with the meta files of the C# scripts to determine which script this GUID refers to. Alternatively, you can try to resolve the path to the asset from the GUID using the [`AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath.html) method.

Comment: Nice! Now I can find all public fields in the text scene file. My scripts are missing because of GUID change after an awful plugin upgrade.

Comment: How do you cross-reference the meta files to quickly find one that contains the GUID?